# Incluir valor por defecto en una restricción JS

Tags: javascript

Estoy haciendo pruebas de validar coordenadas con JavaScript, el problema me está dando cuando intento poner la coordenada por defecto (1,1); esto es, se pasa al caso de fuera de rango. Aquí el trozo de código:

```javascript
    if (x_1 != 1 && y_1 != 1) {
      if (isNaN(x_1) || x_1 == 0 || x_1 % 1 != 0) {
        mensaje = mensaje + "El valor de la coordenada X introducido no tiene un formato correcto. \n";
        errores = 1;
      }
      if (isNaN(y_1) || y_1 == 0 || y_1 % 1 != 0) {
        mensaje = mensaje + "El valor en la coordenada Y introducido no tiene un formato correcto. \n";
        errores = 1;
      }
      if (x_1 > 710000 || x_1 < 470000) {
        mensaje = mensaje + "El valor de la coordenada X introducido se encuentra fuera de rango. \n";
        errores = 1;
      }
      if (y_1 > 4300000 || y_1 < 4100000) {
        mensaje = mensaje + "El valor de la coordenada Y introducido se encuentra fuera de rango. \n";
        errores = 1;
      }
    }
```

Mi consulta, ¿tengo que hacer un `break` o cambiar los `if` por `switch`?.

Comment: (1, 1) está fuera de rango: ambos valores son menores a 470000 y 4100000, respectivamente. Los valores, según tienes escritas las condiciones, han de estar entre 710000 y 470000 (x) y entre 4300000 y 4100000 (y)

Comment: Hola @PabloLozano, muy buenos días! Eso sí que es comprensible, digno de agradecer. Lo que no entiendo es, que al indicar ese valor por defecto, vuelva al if que comprueba el fuera de rango.

Comment: No sé cómo es el flujo de tu código, es complicado ayudar más sin un [mcve]

Comment: Editado, compañero, haz tus propias reflexiones ;)

Comment: ¿Qué son x, y, x_1 y y_1? Ya estamos hablando de 4 variables

Comment: Ha sido una errata mía, perdón xD Ahora sí que son 2 variables.

Comment: `y_1 % 1 != 0` -- Qué crees tú que hace esta línea? me parece que el `isNaN` está demás si estás comparando con coersión (==). Tienes que estudiar mejor los operadores lógicos de comparación, y saber la diferencia entre el AND y el OR, y sus tablas de verdad.

Comment: Pues parece que no estás pasando realmente (1,1), porque en ese caso no se ejecuta ninguna comprobación posterior. De hecho, la comprobación inicial hace que (1,N) y (N,1), para cualquier N, se ignoren las comprobaciones

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
let x_1 = 10;
let y_1 = 14000;
let mensaje = "";
let errores = 0;
if( ! ( x_1 == 1 && y_1 == 1 ) ) {
    if( x_1 == 0 || x_1 % 1 != 0 ) {
        mensaje = mensaje + "El valor de la coordenada X introducido no tiene un formato correcto. \n";
        errores += 1;
    }
    if( y_1 == 0 || y_1 % 1 != 0 ) {
        mensaje = mensaje + "El valor en la coordenada Y introducido no tiene un formato correcto. \n";
        errores += 1;
console.log( "sip" );
    }
    if( x_1 > 710000 || x_1 < 470000 )  {
        mensaje = mensaje + "El valor de la coordenada X introducido se encuentra fuera de rango. \n";
        errores += 1;
    }
    if( y_1 > 4300000 || y_1 < 4100000 ) {
        mensaje = mensaje + "El valor de la coordenada Y introducido se encuentra fuera de rango. \n";
        errores += 1;
    }
}
else {
    mensaje += "default";
}
console.log( mensaje );
console.log( errores );
```

Modificando el primer if, para que detecte la entrada default, y agregando el correspondiente else (si es necesario), funciona correctamente, como comentó @Arriel, he quitado los **isNaN**, ya que con **x_1 % 1 != 0** es suficiente.

Comment: Hola, @MarcePuente y demás! Tiene más sentido, entiendo más claro. Lo probaré, muchas gracias! :)